# Java Socket multiple requests

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have built a small webserver which accepts requests. Problem is that if I open it inside my browser my application shows that 4 requests have been received. Why 4 and not just 1?

```
while (true) {
        try {
            Socket remote = s.accept();

            String sendersIP = remote.getInetAddress().toString();
            log.add(sendersIP);

                System.out.println("Got new Request");

                out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
                out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                out.println("Server: Bot");
                out.println("");
                out.println("<H1>Welcome</H1>");

            out.flush();
            remote.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That depends on what you browser does.  Most likely it is asking for different pages to cache information like how the web server is used. Shouldn't the HTML have a BODY section?

Comment: Could you please show the declaration of `out`?

Comment: The line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not whatever the platform serves up for `println()`.

Comment: @mike PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(remote.getOutputStream());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was my browsers (Chrome) mistake... If I send a request from eclipse it only appears once.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the `while` just for accepting clients.
Create a new thread where you handle everything related to `Socket remote`.

The thread should also have a while loop, where it reads from `remote`s `InputStream`
and don't close the socket right after creation. Then you can see what exactly your browser sends.

Because the way it is right now. You close the socket to the browser right after creation.